# could not find main class in eclipse while running

Tags: java, eclipse

Everytime I try to run this program it's showing up could not load main class. I have informations in Player class and testing it through TestPlayer class which has the main method:

[image]

Comment: Please change your class name TestPlayer.java to Player.java.

Comment: Looks like you are running the wrong class. Right click on TestPlayer and select 'Run As > Java Application'

Answer (score 0):

In your main method **`String[] args` is missing** so technically, it is not a main method that can be used to start a Java application:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //...
}
```